# Nano edit, permission denied

Tags: 14.04, permissions, sudo, aws, nano

I am trying to edit a index.php by using `sudo nano index.php`.
Nano opens me into `index.php`, then i add the code into the file, save and try to exit but it says `permission denied`. I am using `ssh` session in terminal and also Amazon web services... I am signed in on an ubuntu@IPADDRESS. any help?

Answer (score 2):

While your user may have permission to read the file, your user doesn't have permission to write the file.

Use `ls -l <filename>` to list permissions, owner and group of the file.
If appropriate, change permissions or owner so you can write to the file.

#### How to use the `chown` command

`chown` changes the user and/or group ownership of for given file. The syntax is:

```
chown owner-user file
chown owner-user:owner-group file
chown owner-user:owner-group directory
chown options owner-user:owner-group file
```

#### How to use the `chmod` command

To setup file permission you need to use `chmod`, its syntax is `chmod <mode> <filename>`

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer to include the steps to chown and chmod.

Comment: the OP says he used `sudo`. Why is `chown/chmod` necessary?